# how to store rabbitMQ messages

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I am using a RabbitMQ server with python for sending and receiving messages to the server
This is the code I am using for sending a message in to code.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pika

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
             host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue_declare(queue='Q1')
message = 'Hello World'
channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                      routing_key='Q1',
                      body=message)
# Printing the Sending Confirmation of ID
print(" [x] Sent %r" % message)

connection.close()
```

**Output**:

```
[x] Sent 'Hello World'
```

This is the code I am using for receiving messages from queue

```
import pika
import sys

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue_declare(queue='Q1')
def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print(" [x] Received %r" % body)

channel.basic_consume(callback, queue='Q1', no_ack=True)
channel.start_consuming()
```

**Output**:

```
[x] Received 'Hello World'
```

The problem is I want to save this message i.e. "Hello World" to a variable and then use it in my program

But I am not able to save the message.

How can I save it to a variable.
What will be the solution for Multiple Messages in the queue

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is I want to save this message i.e. "Hello World" to a variable and then use it in my program

You've got a variable already which you can use in you program - `body`. If you'd like to decouple the *infrastructure code* (i.e. RabbitMq/pika) from the *business logic* then you can simply declare another function and pass the `body` to it.

```
def processing_function(message_received):
    print(" [x] Received %r" % message_received)

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    processing_function(body)
```

The idea is that pika calls `callback` once a message is received and then `body` is passed to the `processing_function` which performs calculations.

If you're struggling to understand the callback function I'd recommend you to read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)) first.